# Wordpress Smilies for certain levels of members

Tags: php, wordpress, block, membership, emoticons

Hello, I am trying to setup my wordpress website with a membership plugin (right now trying Paid Membership Pro), and I am trying to make it where certain membership levels are either are granted access to the wordpress smilies (emoticons). To a further extent I would love to have certain membership levels have access to different smilies.

Paid Membership Pro gives an example of code to grant access to things in your theme based on membership level, but the code for the smilies are not in that folder.

Example Code:

```
<?php
    if(pmpro_hasMembershipLevel('Gold'))
    {
    ?>
        //Place your HTML or PHP code here if the user is in the required membership level
        ...
    <?php
    }
?>
```

I have tried to add this code (without the PHP breaking for html) into the function.php in the wp-includes/ folder.

So my code in wordpress's (NOT the theme's) function.php looks like:

```
function smilies_init() {
    global $wpsmiliestrans, $wp_smiliessearch;

    // don't bother setting up smilies if they are disabled
    if ( !get_option( 'use_smilies' ) )
        return;
    if(pmpro_hasMembershipLevel('Platinum'))
    { 
        if ( !isset( $wpsmiliestrans ) ) {
            $wpsmiliestrans = array(
            //The list of smilies are here and very long so this is a placeholder
            );
        }
    }
    //And the rest of the code in this function I have not modified
```

With that method nothing is changed when someone comments a smilies and is not 'Platinum' and that membership level does exist. I am not sure if I need to link the Paid Membership Pro code (which I have not tried or looked for yet) or something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated.